# Flex GroupingCollection: Loop through the children

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe, advanceddatagrid

I am using a GroupingCollection to bind my advanceddatagrid. I have used groupingcollection to group the data by date.

Now I need to select the data in the datagrid through the code. Does anyone have any idea as to how to do this? I need to loop through the adg's dataprovider and select the item that matches the criteria for the selection.

Please advise

Thanks :)

Comment: Does the GroupingCollection have a source?

Comment: Do you mean you want to show them as selected in the datagrid?  Or when somebody clicks on the datagrid you need to get the item data selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, depending on how the question in interpreted, this code will find the items that match the grouping year that is selected.  I added a `click=findStuff(event)` to the `mx:AdvancedDataGrid`, as shown here:

```
[Bindable]  
public var myData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {name:'Denise', grad:'2000'},
    {name:'Steph', grad:'1990'},
    {name:'Jane', grad:'2000'},
    {name:'Nicole', grad:'2000'},
    {name:'Donna', grad:'1990'}]);

public function findStuff(e:Event):void {
    var groupColl:GroupingCollection = adGrid.dataProvider.source;
    var items:Object = groupColl.source;

    var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    for (var i:int=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].grad == e.target.text) {
            ac.addItem(items[i].name);
        }
    }
    Alert.show("selected items: " + ac.toArray());
}

<mx:GroupingCollection id="coll" source="{myData}">
    <mx:Grouping>
        <mx:GroupingField name="grad" />
    </mx:Grouping>
</mx:GroupingCollection>

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="adGrid" dataProvider="{coll}"
                         click="findStuff(event)"
                         initialize="coll.refresh()">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="name" dataField="name"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Note that first I get the GroupingCollection from the AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider, then I get the items from the GroupingCollection. These could be combined into one step, but this way is more readable for the example.  Not knowing exactly what data you're looking for I just grab the `name` field from the data `item` but there's no reason you couldn't grab the whole `item`.

Hopefully this is a step in the right direction for you.

Comment: Thanks dustmachine. I will try this one. The scenario is, I have an arraycollection bound to a grid. My app has an option to group by date. Now, when I group by date, I change the dataprovider to groupingcollection. So, when my dataprovider is changed, I wanted to maintain the state of the selected item in the grid. So that when I change the dataprovider, I can programatically select the item in the grid. I will give this one a try

Comment: You could try to manipulate the adGrid to highlight the proper rows by sticking `adGrid.selectedItems = ac.toArray();` just above the `Alert.show` in the above code.  If the rows/items are in a tree/folder that's closed then they probably won't show...      An upvote would be appreciated if this solves it for you.

Comment: Sure. Let me try this.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `source` property should contain the flat representation of the data.

Comment: Yes. Grouping collection is bound to the arraycollection.
its a flat list of objects. But, how should I loop and select the desired child? You have any clue about it?

Comment: you can just loop through it until it matches what you have selected.